# Undocumented Dynamic Function question

Tags: dynamic

In the code below the value displayed next to the slider may be correct, and should be the result of The value of `x` for `cyL` and the value of `x` for change at the slider position.  Slider position 0 should provide the first values for `x` in these lines.  Now if I evaluate `x`outside of the function after moving the sliders, it only returns the slider position and not the value of `x` from the function.  How can I get the variable to return the correct value for each slider?  Thanks!

```
cyL[x_] := 
  58.770000000000046` - 3.557000000000158` x - 
   3.525333333333144` x^2 + 4.987999999999908` x^3 - 
   1.3386666666666487` x^4;

cyA[y_] := -35.13365403304179` - 0.009572400388682331` y + 
   0.08989310009715228` y^2 - 0.01687074829931251` y^3;

change[x_] := -0.17006802721089645` + 62.92517006802724` x - 
   6.802721088435384` x^2;

Column[{{Slider[Dynamic[x, Automatic]], 
   Dynamic[cyL[change[x]]]}, {Slider[Dynamic[g, Automatic]], 
   Dynamic[cyA[change[g]]]}}]
```

Comment: Works fine for me on OS X MMA 8.0.4. I get 59.2473 for the first number at slider position 0 and -35.1293 for the second.

Comment: for the value of x or the displayed value of the slider?  If I check the value of x at any slider position, I just get the slider position,  I'm also on MM 8.04 OSX  Try evaluating x outside of the function.  That produces the slider position,  I need the displayed value.

Comment: Aaah. I see. you want to access the value of cyL[x] outside of the Slider. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, well the result of x for cyL[change[x] yes thanks.  I need to pass that number outside of the Dynamic to another function and then to a plot.

Comment: I meant the value displayed next to the slider. I'm sorry if I didn't understand your question correctly. Do you want to display x, change[x], cyL[x]. cyL[change[x]], or something else? Or do you want the access any (and which) of those outside of the slider?

Comment: I don't get what's the problem. I think it's working fine. x and g have position value of the slider and cyL[change[x]] the right function value.

Comment: At present when I move the slider to the right I get a value of -4902.59 and if I evaluate x in another cell I get 0.145.  I need to return the value of the slider cyL[change[x]]to another function, as a variable.

Comment: Just do func[cyL[change[x]]]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After your last comment, maybe you should assing the value of cyL[change[x]] to another variable in the dynamic, and use it outside. Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @FJRA! Works perfectly!!